# How can I access the list of modules that Python's help('modules') displays?

Tags: python, python-module

How can I access the list of modules that Python's `help('modules')` displays? It shows the following:

```
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

...[list of modules]...
MySQLdb             codeop              mailman_sf          spwd
OpenSSL             collections         markupbase          sqlite3
Queue               colorsys            marshal             sre
...[list of modules]...

Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose descriptions contain the word "spam".

>>>
```

I can view the list in the output but would like to access this as a list from within a Python program. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mimic all the `help` does by yourself.  Built-in `help` uses `pydoc`, that uses `ModuleScanner` class to get information about all available libs - see line 1873 in [pydoc.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/pydoc.py?view=markup).

Here is a bit modified version of code from the link:

```
>>> modules = []
>>> def callback(path, modname, desc, modules=modules):
    if modname and modname[-9:] == '.__init__':
        modname = modname[:-9] + ' (package)'
    if modname.find('.') < 0:
        modules.append(modname)

>>> def onerror(modname):
    callback(None, modname, None)

>>> from pydoc import ModuleScanner 
>>> ModuleScanner().run(callback, onerror=onerror)
>>> len(modules)
379
>>> modules[:10]
['__builtin__', '_ast', '_bisect', '_codecs', '_codecs_cn', '_codecs_hk', '_codecs_iso2022', '_codecs_jp', '_codecs_kr', '_codecs_tw']
>>> len(modules)
379
```

Comment: Note that this uses a private class and could theoretically break one day if the internals are changed.  It is unlikely, though.

Comment: SO what returned the help of module ?

Answer (score 2):

There are more then one way. You could try:

```
import sys

mod_dict = sys.modules

for k,v in mod_dict.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

Comment: This won't work, because it only shows the modules that have _already been_ imported. In contrast, `help('modules')` shows all the modules that are _currently available_ for importing (which is obviously a much longer list - unless you've already used `help`, that is ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Those will only list modules not included in the standard library,
but may be useful,

subprocess.call(
[pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) freeze)

subprocess.call(
[yolk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk)  -l)

Answer (score 1):

The list of modules comes ultimately from a combination of [sys.builtin_module_names](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) and the output of [pkgutil.walk_packages](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages):

```
import sys
from pkgutil import walk_packages

modules = set()

def callback(name, modules=modules):
    if name.endswith('.__init__'):
        name = name[:-9] + ' (package)'
    if name.find('.') < 0:
        modules.add(name)

for name in sys.builtin_module_names:
    if name != '__main__':
        callback(name)

for item in walk_packages(onerror=callback):
    callback(item[1])

for name in sorted(modules, key=lambda n: n.lower()):
    print name
```

It should be noted that creating the list has the consequnce that all the modules will be imported (you can easily verify this for yourself by checking the length of `sys.modules` before and after calling `help('modules')`).

Another thing to note is that the output of `walk_packages` depends on the current state of `sys.path` - so the results may not always match the output of `help`.

Comment: I’m curious about your last point; doesn’t help walk sys.path just like pkgutil?

Comment: @ÉricAraujo. The first entry in `sys.path` will differ depending on whether Python is run interactively, or from a script. Since the `help` function is normally used in an interactive session, `sys.path[0]` will point to the current directory, rather than the script's directory - which _may_ be the same, but usually won't be.